# I'm new to python and can't figure how to make a status changer for a discord bot

Tags: python, discord.py

So I have a code that will put up a status (at bottom) but I'm new to python and scripting all together, an anybody help?

I've tried doing this =

```
@client.event
async def on_ready()
    await client_presence(activity=discord.Activity(name= "test1", "test2", "test3", type=discord.ActivityType.watching))
```

but of course that didn't work because its just going to use "test1" and now I have no idea what to do so I came here!

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
      await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(name="You type !help | Made by Iharvested, type !baselink to obtain me!", type=discord.ActivityType.watching))
```

Comment: This seems to be about [tag:discord.py] and not [tag:discord.js].

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking for a way in which you infinitely loop over a bunch of different status's, this is your best bet.

```
statusList = ["test1", "test2", "test3"]

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    while True:
        for status in statusList:
            await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(name=status, type=discord.ActivityType.watching))
```